# Try to find KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileScript method in Kotlin 1.4.10

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

During migration my java project from Kotlin 1.2 to 1.4 I ran into a problem that there is no such method as KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileScript() in v 1.4

```
Class<?> script = requireNonNull(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.INSTANCE.compileScript(environment, getClass().getClassLoader()), () -> file + " compilation failed");
```

Please suggest me what should I replace this with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this removal commit on github https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/d863dc04e60ce82a162dbc4b5f1c9d379806177a#diff-36340d5f4473fd26b6fd3d39ac22b10560a53da22b65c763ba0b9e4d9864a18e

Then maybe you can see what you need to do to migrate your code to a new version, if not then maybe raise an issue on github that this public function has been removed without any info how to migrate to something new